# Laravel Relationship Issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables in my laravel application...
users and birthdays table..
The birthdays table stores the birthday messages sent by users....

I have a view that displays users which today is their birthday..
I want to filter out the ones that the `Auth::user()` has already messaged in the current year...

Here is my BirthdaysController code

```
$birthdays = User::withTrashed()->where('dob', date('m-d'))->get();

    $hasSentMessage = [];
    foreach($birthdays as $birthday)
    {
        $hasSentMessageToUser = false;
        $birthdayMessage = Birthday::where('sender', Auth::user()->id)->where('user_id', $birthday->id)->where('year', date('Y'))->first();
        if($birthdayMessage)
        {
            $hasSentMessageToUser = true;
        }
        array_push($hasSentMessage, $hasSentMessageToUser);
    }
```

Question is, how do i ignore the user that the `Auth::user()` has already messaged so i can display the others that hasn't been messaged

Thanks alot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get users who have a birthday to which you haven't sent messages in current year. Im not sure it solves your problem exactly because I dont quite understand everything, but... I do my best to help to you. :D

```
$users_with_birthdays = User::withTrashed()
    ->doesntMessaged()
    ->where('dob', '=', date('m-d'))
    ->get();
```

Now implement your scopeDoesntMessaged() in User model like

```
public function scopeDoesntMessaged($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('birthdayMessages', function ($q) {
        return $q->where('sender', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('year', '=', date('Y'));
    });
}
```

Which needs relation...

```
public function birthdayMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Birthday::class)
}
```